# SKYPE on ubuntu 14-04 -- how to upgrade it?

Tags: ubuntu, skype

SKYPE has upgraded its soft some while ago, and I missed my chance to reinstall it at that point. One of my  comps run ubuntu 12-something, and I guess it is hopeless  now to reactivate SKYPE on it now without upgrading it to a more recent ubuntu release (and I hate doing that), while another one (laptop  Dell Precision 5510) runs ubuntu 14-04, and I hope it would accept latest SKYPE soft. If this is still doable, how do I do it?  Thanks!!!

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/409433/117549

Answer (score 1):

### Skype snap package

You don't need to the download the .deb package for Skype for Linux or install Skype from a PPA anymore. Skype has been released as a native snap package in **Ubuntu 14.04 and later**.

```
snap find skype
Name      Version      Developer  Notes    Summary
skype     8.33.0.41    skype      classic  One Skype for all your devices. New features. New look. All Skype.
```

To install Skype in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install skype --classic
```

The skype snap package will be updated automatically when updates are available.

After you have tested that the skype snap package is working correctly you can uninstall the old version of Skype that you were using before.

#### Ubuntu 12.04

Ubuntu 12.04 is no longer getting software updates and does not support installing snap packages, so download the Skype for Linux .deb package instead or else upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to a **more recent Ubuntu LTS release**. Ubuntu 12.04 is an end of life release. To resolve package dependencies in Ubuntu 12.04, you need to read [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release).

Open the terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
wget https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb
sudo apt install ./skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

When you install the Skype for Linux .deb package it automatically adds a repository to keep your installation of Skype up to date.

Comment: thanks, will try immediately on 14-04!!!